# jQuery window.resize not triggering

Tags: jquery, resize

I am trying to create this navigation, that triggers a jQuery animation when I hover over it.
I am trying to remove the hover functionality, when the browser window is less then 995 px. It won't remove the functionality on window resize, only when I reload the browser.

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
if ($(this).width() > 995) {
  $("#main-nav a").hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({
            padding: "2px 4px 0px 83px", 
            backgroundColor: "#47c7ee", 
            color: "#ffffff"});
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('animated').animate({
                padding: "2px 4px 0 53px", 
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff", 
                color: "#a9a9a9"
            },
            "normal", "linear", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
                $(".active").css({
                    "background-color": "#47c7ee",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "padding": "2px 4px 0px 83px"
                });
            });
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Then I am calling it here on window reload.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).resize(); 
});
```

I can't seem to figure out why and how else I should fix it.

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).resize(function(){ /* your code */ }).trigger('resize'); 
});`?

Comment: `$(window).resize` is working just fine. There must be something else that is wrong with your code. What version of jQuery are you using, and have you tried logging the event to the console?

Comment: The window resize event will be fired thousands of times when you resize the window in most browsers, and every fracking time you are binding a new event handler to your anchors. What could possibly go wrong ?

Comment: @adeneo Good point. I didn't even look that far into his code ;)

Comment: Good point @adeneo. OP: why not just check the window width on hover? If it's `> 995` then run the code, otherwise don't run it.

Comment: Yeah, but it still won't disable the functionality when i resize the window down.

Comment: No it won't, you have to just forget about resize, and just check the windows width inside the mouseenter / leave handlers.

Comment: @Joe - Will try and check the width on the hover instead. Seems like a way better approach to it.

Comment: Yeah @adeneo,didn't think of that. Will try that out now.

Comment: Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/3PX4P/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As have been suggested by [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287470/joe) in the comments, you should check the window size on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. Something like this:

```
$("#main-nav a").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Don't do anything if window size is less than 995px or
    // if the anchor has the active class
    if ($(window).width() < 995 || !$this.hasClass('active')) return;

    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
        $this.dequeue().stop().animate({
                padding: "2px 4px 0px 83px", 
                backgroundColor: "#47c7ee", 
                color: "#ffffff"});
            });
    } else {
        $this.addClass('animated').animate({
                padding: "2px 4px 0 53px", 
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff", 
                color: "#a9a9a9"
            },
            "normal", "linear", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
                $(".active").css({
                    "background-color": "#47c7ee",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "padding": "2px 4px 0px 83px"
                });
            });
    });
});
```

*Note: I haven't tested the code, so I don't know if it will work out of the box.*

Comment: Using mouseenter and mouseleave worked perfectly. 
probably also why I wasn't able to find anything about it in my searches, with the resize approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use something like [mediaCheck](https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck). Simply define a entry and exit function when you cross 995px.

```
mediaCheck({
  media: '(max-width: 995px)',
  entry: function() {
    console.log('starting 955');
  },
  exit: function() {
    console.log('leaving 955');
  },
  both: function() {
    console.log('changing state');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the mouse events worked perfectly. Here is what I came up with

```
$("#main-nav a").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

var $this = $(this);

if (!$(this).hasClass('active') && ($(window).width() > 995)) {

    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({
            padding: "2px 4px 0px 83px",
            backgroundColor: "#47c7ee",
            color: "#ffffff"
        });
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('animated').animate({
            padding: "2px 4px 0 53px",
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: "#a9a9a9"
        }, "normal", "linear", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
            $(".active").css({
                "background-color": "#47c7ee",
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "padding": "2px 4px 0px 83px"
            });
            $("#main-nav a").removeAttr("style");
        });
    }
}
});
```